# PyOpenGL how to rotate a scene with the mouse

Tags: python, pygame, blender, pyopengl

I am trying to create a simple scene in 3d (in python) where you have a cube in front of you, and you are able to rotate it around with the mouse. 
I understand that you should rotate the complete scene to mimic camera movement but i can't figure out how you should do this.
Just to clarify I want the camera (or scene) to move a bit like blender (the program).

Thanks in advance

Comment: I think what you wanted is called arcball rotation. It is quite easily searchable. If and when you have problems with implementation, then post your code.

Comment: Thank you for your answer although it was not completely what I was looking for, but i have found what I should do

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I think i have found what you should do
just for the people that have trouble with this like I did this is the way you should do it:

to rotate around a cube with the camera in opengl:

your x mouse value has to be added to the z rotator of your scene

and the cosinus of your y mouse value has to be added to the x rotator
and then the sinus of your y mouse value has to be subtracted of your y rotator

that should do it